# Electromagnetic wave in a medium with $\sigma \ne 0$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetic-radiation, reflection

I want to prove that the reflectancy of an Electromagnetic wave in a medium with $\sigma$ $\ne$ 0 is:

\begin{align*}
R_{\|}=R_{\perp}=\frac{(n-1)^2+k^2}{(n+1)^2+k^2}
\end{align*}

any advice, please?

Comment: Have you tried setting up and solving a simple boundary value problem?

Comment: Like in a potential well? @peanut_butter ?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. Assuming this is for class, your text book should have something for this. Another handy reference to get you going: [Electromagnetic Boundary conditions](http://local.eleceng.uct.ac.za/courses/EEE3055F/lecture_notes/2011_old/eee3055f_Ch4_2up.pdf)

Comment: Thanks @peanut_butter! I will give it a try. And yes, it is for a class, I have a test soon. We are working with the books of Optics of Hecht, but they don't discuss this very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a plane wave, all Cartesian field component space and time dependencies are $exp(i\,\vec{k}\,\vec{x}-i\,\omega\,t)$: time derivatives $f\mapsto \mathrm{d}_t f$ become $f\mapsto\,-i\,\omega\,f$ and vector curls $\vec{F}\mapsto\nabla\times\vec{F}$ become $\vec{F}\mapsto i\,\vec{k}\times\vec{F}$. So now we recallAmpère's law in time-harmonic form:

$$\begin{array}{lclcl}&\nabla\times H &=& \vec{J}+\partial_t\vec{D}\\\Rightarrow&\vec{E}&=&\frac{i}{\sigma -i\,\omega\,\epsilon}\vec{k}\times\vec{H}\end{array}\tag{1}$$

So you see from this that $\vec{E},\,\vec{k},\,\vec{H}$, in that order, form a right handed triple of mutually orthogonal vectors. On the incidence side of the boundary, assumed normal to $\vec{k}$, there are *two* such triples: an incident wave with electric field $\vec{E}^+$ and a reflected wave $\vec{E}^-$ (this one has wavevector $-\vec{k}$. On the transmission side there is only one triple with electric field $E^T$. Now we simply equate electric fields at the boundary (they are all in the same direction, so we only need signed scalars henceforth), since tangential $\vec{E}$ must be continuous across it:

$$E^+ + E^- = E^T\tag{2}$$

and use (1) to equate the magnetic fields at the boundary so as to fulfill the boundary condition that $\vec{H}$ must be continuous across the boundary. We note that the magnetic fields too are all in the same direction (orthogonal to the $\vec{E}$s), so signed scalars work here too:

$$\frac{-1}{\omega\,\epsilon_0}(E^+ - E^-) = \frac{i}{\sigma -i\,\omega\,\epsilon}\,E^T\tag{3}$$

Note the minus sign on the LHS between the two $E$s: $E^+ - E^-$: this is because $\vec{k}$ is in the opposite direction for the reflected wave. You should now be able to find $E^-$ and $E^T$ in terms of $E^+$ from (2) and (3) and then use Maxwell's relationship $\epsilon = n^2$ to simplify.